# Removing an auto-generated slot method

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, when in the designer, you can right click on a component and select "Go to slots ...". A dialogue box opens allowing you to select a slot ... for example Clicked().  When selecting one and clickibng the OK button you are taken to the forms cpp file and the associated event / slot / method.

Say, in a moment of enthusiasm one creates all available events/methods for a particular component on the form - how does one get rid of them again?

Comment: You should remove the slots from`.h` file and `.cpp` file of your class.

Comment: Thanks, Nejat.  I thought I'd tried that.  I kept getting a compile error in a file called something like ui_mainwindow.h  in the middle of a case statement.  I tried what you suggested and it works, so thanks.